# Mounting HFS+ (hfsplus) RAID 1 under Linux 3.13

Tags: linux, macos, mount, raid-1, hfs+

I'm using a Linux Mint liveCD to rescue data off a Hackintosh which had its boot drive fail. I also have an HFS+ RAID 1 (created with Disk Utility in OS X) on separate drives in the system.  Theoretically these are just mirror images of each other, but Linux won't mount them from the GUI or the command line.  I don't care about mounting read/write, I only need read-only to pull data off.  The RAID volumes are 1500GB each for a total of 1500GB mirrored, so it's not a >2TB issue.

The error I get, despite Mint's GUI being able to see the name of the RAID volume on both drives ("MirrorMirror"), is the same in both GUI or command line. Note I am attempting to mount just one mirror of the RAID - I don't care about mounting both, I am pretty sure they're in good shape and just want to read data off one of the mirrored partitions.

```
# mount -t hfsplus -o ro /dev/sdi2 mirror

mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdi2,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

And doing what it suggests yields:

```
hfsplus: invalid secondary volume header
hfsplus: unable to find HFS+ superblock
```

When I take a peek ('print all') with 'parted' I see "Raid Partition 1" on /dev/sdi2 and "Raid Partition 2" on /dev/sda2.  I am pretty sure this is correct.

My guess is that there's a flag written somewhere that says "hey, I'm a RAID 1 partition" and that mount.hfsplus is barfing on it. Any ideas?

Comment: Possibly related: https://superuser.com/questions/657655/problems-with-mounting-hfs-drives