# Mounting HFS+ partition in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssd, mount, hfs+

**Update:** I was able to solve the problem with [this](https://superuser.com/questions/961401/mounting-hfs-partition-on-arch-linux/1088110#1088110) solution

I want to read data from my SSD from my broken MacBook. 
I connected it to my Ubuntu 16.04 PC and used the command given in [the third answer](https://superuser.com/questions/84446/how-to-mount-a-hfs-partition-in-ubuntu-as-read-write/365270#365270?newreg=880015dc3d3c491484339dabd630c486):

```
sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw /dev/sdx# /media/mntpoint
```

which produces the following error:

```
wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb2,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error

   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.
```

The syslog produces the following output:

```
[  294.856309] hfsplus: invalid secondary volume header
[  294.856312] hfsplus: unable to find HFS+ superblock
```

`parted` shows the file format to be `hfs+`:

```
Model: ATA APPLE SSD SM256E (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 251GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                  Flags
 1      20,5kB  210MB  210MB  fat32        EFI system partition  boot, esp
 2      210MB   250GB  250GB  hfs+         Macintosh HD
 3      250GB   251GB  650MB  hfs+         Recovery HD
```

However, `fdisk` shows it as Apple Core storage:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 233,8 GiB, 251000193024 bytes, 490234752 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 00003592-7281-0000-4046-000013340000

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1         40    409639    409600   200M EFI System
/dev/sdb2     409640 488965175 488555536   233G Apple Core storage
/dev/sdb3  488965176 490234711   1269536 619,9M Apple boot
```

Is this the cause of the problem? Any ideas how I can mount the SSD?

Comment: Are you sure, that your device is still using the `HFS+` file system and not the new `APFS` file system?

Comment: I am not sure but `parted` suggests so.

Comment: It's good you were able to solve the problem. Consider writing an answer; it would be so much better than putting the solution into the question. This is how Q&A sites work. See: *[Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the problem was that the Apple Core Storage is a Wrapper around the HFS+ Partition. This shifts the size of the actual partition slighly, so you one has to specify the partitionsize explicitly.

This procedure is described in detail in [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/961401/mounting-hfs-partition-on-arch-linux/1088110#1088110)