# Unable to mount a HFS+ image due to error on loop

Tags: linux, hard-drive, mount, hard-drive-recovery, hfs+

I am trying to mount an image of a macbook pro obtain with `dd`. I have use [this strategy](https://superuser.com/questions/961401/mounting-hfs-partition-on-arch-linux/1088110#1088110) to adapted the syntax of my mount command.

I have use the following process

- create the image: `sudo dd if=/dev/sdc of=ddDisk bs=300M status=progress`
- obtain the property of the image with `fdisk -l` and `testdisk` (see below)
- create an empty directory: `mkdir test`
- try to mount the main partition (`ddDisk2`) with the following command: `sudo mount -v -t hfsplus -o sizelimit=498887294976 ddDisk2 test`

I obtain the following error message: `mount: test: failed to setup loop device for ddDisk2.` I am not sure I well understand this message.

**Results of `fdisk -l`**

```
Disk ddDisk: 465,8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes 
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes 
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes 
Disklabel type: gpt 
Disk identifier: C83292DE-1D21-4967-8FCA-2A6C377E6F39

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type 
ddDisk1          40    409639    409600   200M EFI System 
ddDisk2      409640 975503591 975093952   465G Apple Core storage 
ddDisk3   975503592 976773127   1269536 619,9M Apple boot
```

**Results of `testdisk`**

```
TestDisk 7.0, Data Recovery Utility, April 2015
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org

Disk ddDisk - 500 GB / 465 GiB - CHS 60802 255 63
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
>P EFI System                    40     409639     409600 [EFI]
 P Mac HFS                   409640  974798887  974389248
 D Mac HFS                975503592  975765735     262144
 D Mac HFS                975503592  976773127    1269536
```

Answer (score 1):

Mount only the partition, not the whole image.

```
losetup -f /dev/loop4 ddDisk -o 209735680
mount -t hfsplus /dev/loop4 test
```

(209735680 is the first byte of the partition)

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I obtain the following error `losetup: /dev/loop4: failed to set up loop device: Invalid argument`

Comment: Then try lower free loop device, e.g. loop1. (`ls /dev/loop*`)

Comment: And make sure `loop` module is loaded to kernel. (`modprobe loop`)

Comment: I have tried on `loop0`: `losetup: /dev/loop0: failed to use backing file: Cannot allocate memory`

Comment: `modprobe loop` returns nothing